# Howto use custom JMXAuthenticator

Tags: jmx

I have to authenticate JMX clients against entries in a database. Therefore I have written a custom JMXAuthenticator implementation.

When starting up my application I can access the MBeans using JConsole via the 'Local Process'. But when I try to access it as a remote process using the url 'service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:10999/jmxrmi' JConsole shows a message complaining that 'The connection to service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:10999/jmxrmi did not succeed.'

Below is the server side code to start up the MBeanServer and the JMXConnectorServer. Has anybody an idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Thomas

```
final MBeanServer mbs = MBeanServerFactory.createMBeanServer("MyDomain");
final HashMap<String, Object> environment = new HashMap<String, Object>();
final JMXAuthenticator authenticator = new JMXAuthenticatorImpl();
environment.put(JMXConnectorServer.AUTHENTICATOR, authenticator);

final JMXServiceURL serviceURL = new JMXServiceURL("rmi", "localhost", 10999);

final JMXConnectorServer connectorServer = JMXConnectorServerFactory.newJMXConnectorServer(serviceURL, environment, mbs);

connectorServer.start();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the problem was that I have not created the RMI Registry before creating the new JMXConnectorServer.

Inserting

```
LocateRegistry.createRegistry(port);
```

before creating the JMXConnectorServer solved the problem.